# How to disable the sort options in the filter menu?

Tags: excel, vba

When sorting data using the little filter dropdown menu, you can't undo your changes, which can really mess up the order of the data. My fellow employees know this, but sometimes someone clicks sort instead of filter accidentally and we need to restore the workbook with an older version. How do I disable the options for everyone?

The upper 3 options is what I am talking about.

[image]

I think adding something like:

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Sort by color?").Visible = False
```

might work, but I don't know exactly what to use instead of "Cell", or what the name of the controls are. Where can I find the names of those?

Comment: Have a hidden sheet with the original data on it. Then  copy/paste that to the work area every time the workbook is closed.

Comment: Or have a sheet where they can get the filtered output instead of letting them work on the source.

Comment: @SolarMike that way users cannot change data.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ there is a BIG difference between sorting, filtering and CHANGING data...

Comment: Or create a column (might be hidden) that can be used to sort the data back to the wanted order.

Comment: @FunThomas seen it often where some forget to make sure they have all the columns selected... so they sort half the columns and the dataset is then rubbish...

Comment: @SolarMike But that does not make any sense because then you can just protect the entire sheet (and just allow filtering).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ obviously you have better users than I do. One time I had one tell me: "i found a complicated formula in your sheet - I did not understand it, so I deleted it"... wtf...

Comment: @SolarMike well for those candidates you protect your sheet (especially formulas)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ oh, I promptly learnt how to protect certain cells, but it was annoying to have to go to that effort for one idiot while 20 people prior had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Protect the worksheet:

1. Remove cell protection from all cells that should be changed by users. (This can be the entire sheet if you want).
2. Protect the worksheet and allow **Autofilter** (and all other options if you like) but disallow **Sorting**.

After that users can filter but cannot sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this macro to disable sorting but allow filtering, call it like `DisableSorting ActiveSheet`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DisableSorting(WS As Worksheet)
    WS.Cells.Locked = False ' a)
    WS.Protect _
        DrawingObjects:=False, _
        Contents:=True, _
        Scenarios:=False, _
        UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
        AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
        AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
        AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
        AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
        AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
        AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, _
        AllowSorting:=False, _
        AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
End Sub
```

<s>Note, however, that editing the cells won't be possible, either. There is no way to disable sorting but enable editing.</s>

**Update 1**

As noted by Pᴇʜ, you can allow filtering and editing while disabling sorting if you add the line marked with a).

**Update 2**

If you want to re-enable sorting, you can use `WS.Unprotect`. If it's easier to remember, you can have a function like this to do it:

```
Public Sub EnableSorting(WS As Worksheet)
    WS.Unprotect
End Sub
```

Comment: Ehhm, ther is a way. Just as I wrote in my answer. This way you can edit the content but sorting is disabled.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: You mean: This way you can _filter_ the content but sorting is disabled?

Comment: No I mean if you don't lock the cells you want to be able to edit you still can disable sorting.

Comment: This works great for disabling sorting. However I would still like to be able to use sorting in the workbook. Ideally It would just hide the option in the menu.

Comment: @ViktorToyot Well there are other ways to sort data in Excel besides that menu. So the only safe way is protecting the sheet, and unprotect it if you want to use it. Note that even if you get managed to hide those menus they will hide for **all** Excel files that are opened while executing that code because `Application.CommandBars` will affect the application Excel and not a specific workbook. That means it affects other files too and you might piss off your users with that because they won't understand why they cannot sort in their own file anymore.